# Poweroff or Reboot as normal User

Tags: permissions, sudo, root, shutdown, reboot

To run the command `poweroff` or `reboot` one needs to be super user. Is there anyway I can run this as a normal user? I just don't want to `sudo` and enter my password every time I reboot or power off.

Comment: The answer depends on which init system your distro uses... For example, with `systemd` and an active `logind` session you can reboot or poweroff without elevated privileges providing no other user is still logged in...

Comment: @jasonwryan I am currently using Ubuntu which doesnot use `systemd` by default.So you mean other Distros such as Arch can reboot without elavated privileges?

Comment: Yes: as per the conditions in my first comment.

Comment: Similar to [Pre-authorise sudo? (So it can be run later)](https://superuser.com/q/640491/354511)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I changed `/etc/sudoers` so that every user that is in the admin group can execute the following commands without being ask for a password.

```
sudo halt
sudo reboot
sudo poweroff
```

You just need to add the following lines to `/etc/sudoers`

```
## Admin user group is allowed to execute halt and reboot 
%admin ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/halt, /sbin/reboot, /sbin/poweroff
```

and add yourself to the admin group.

If you want only one user to be able to do this just remove the `%admin` and replace it with `username` like this

```
## user is allowed to execute halt and reboot 
stormvirux ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/halt, /sbin/reboot, /sbin/poweroff
```

You can find out more about `/etc/sudoers` with `man sudoers` or the [online manpage](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/sudoers.man.html)

Answer (score 9):

You can also create a new file under `/etc/sudoers.d` name it as you wish(I named it `'shutdown'`), and put the following lines inside:

```
# Allows me to shutdown the system without a password

yourUserName ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/halt, /sbin/reboot, /sbin/poweroff
```

Just change "yourUserName" for YOUR  User Name, and add or remove commands to use, personally I use it only for `shutdown`. One of the main difference of creating a particular file under `sudoers.d` is that this file will survive System Upgrades

Comment: If you choose this approach, ensure that `/etc/sudoers` has an appropriate `#include` directive to read files from `/etc/sudoers.d/`.

Comment: Even with the `#includedir` directive, this doesn't work.  When testing this as non-root user with `reboot`, I receive the following:


```Failed to set wall message, ignoring: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to reboot system via logind: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to open initctl fifo: Permission denied
Failed to talk to init daemon.```

Comment: @jimjamz I had that error as well, but then I realized I had to type `sudo reboot` not just `reboot`. No password prompt, but prompt reboot.

Comment: @JoeSkeen I think using `sudo` defeats the whole purpose of this topic and what we're trying to do here.

Comment: True, but for me it was more about not requiring the interactive password prompt, which this fixed, even if you have to use the `sudo` command.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest solution:

```
sudo echo $USER >> /etc/shutdown.allow
```

Then you're able to use one of this commands:

```
shutdown -ah now   // halt
shutdown -ar now   // reboot
```

According [man shutdown](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/sysvinit-core/shutdown.8.en.html) there is **-a** option for non-root usage:

> If `shutdown` is called with the **-a** argument (add this to the invocation of shutdown in */etc/inittab*), it checks to see if the file */etc/shutdown.allow* is present. It then compares the login names in that file with the list of people that are logged in on a virtual console ...

It works in Debian Linux. And there is limit for 32 user names in `/etc/shutdown.allow`.

Comment: No such option on Fedora, CentOS or RHEL.

Comment: This is also not working for Ubuntu, at least that is what I get from the docs. It would be helpful to see if this is a Debian only feature.

Comment: Still not in Ubuntu (18.04) in 2020 =}

Comment: My fresh Debian 12's man entry doesn't talk about shutdown.allow or -a anywhere.  Is there a package I need before it will work like yours?

Comment: This is part of sysvinit-core documentation. Check for more details on [man pages](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/sysvinit-core/shutdown.8.en.html) online.

Answer (score 2):

You can also achieve this by trick with setuid. I don't know if it will work on all systems, because they sometimes ignore setuid/setgid bit.

You can specify a group of users who can perform change of system state in my case it was `adm`. Then add appropriate users to this group.

```
gpasswd -a $USER adm
```

Specify permissions:

```
chmod 4550 /usr/bin/reboot
```

`ls -l` outpus should look like this:

```
-r-sr-x--- 1 root adm 18928 Mar 13  2015 /usr/bin/reboot
```

Afterwards you can just type:

```
reboot
```

Comment: Don't do this with systemd!  With systemd, the `reboot` command is a symlink to `systemctl`, so you'll actually change `systemctl` to be setgid, and systemd does some security stuff (like don't trust env variables in setuid/gid programs) that will break it when setuid/gid.

Comment: I would generally not do this. Setuid is a security risk (see the comment about systemd). Which you can easily avoid using sudo as explained in some of the other answers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but I don't see a security risk here. If `reboot` is a symbolic link then of course don't do it, but if you don't use systemd as an init system and your reboot program is small and does only one thing then everything is Ok. You should just always use some common sense before using whatever solution you've found on the internet.

Regarding an answer involving modification of sudoers file - it still requires to enter `sudo reboot` which doesn't address OP's wish to not write `sudo` at all.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to achieve not only boot privileges but access to all systemctl services for a specific user or group in a Debian system is doing this:

```
sudo chown root:myuserorgroup /bin/systemctl
sudo chmod 4755 /bin/systemctl
```

Because all boot scripts `/sbin/shutdown`, `/sbin/poweroff`, `/sbin/reboot` are links to `/bin/systemctl`, changind its permissions and ownership grants the necessary privilege to execute it as root user.

**Be aware that the user will be able to execute all systemctl operations**. This may sound as a security threat, but it is a simple general solution to embbeded systems where your default user must not only have the access rights to shudown but also to work with all the other system services related to `systemctl`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I have done when I needed this. It may not work if the shutdown needs to happen *right away*, but it has the advantage that it needs neither extra privilege nor `sudo`.

- Create and maintain a directory somewhere (maybe under `/var/tmp`) which is normally empty but fully accessible by you
- When you need to force a shutdown, just touch an empty file into existence in that directory
- A root cron job runs every minute and checks if that file exists
- If so, the cron job removes the file and shuts down.

I did this in the context of shutting down a Raspberry Pi when the UPS hat [1] on it stays on battery power for too long. I wanted to run the monitoring script as a normal user.

1. https://www.pishop.us/raspberry-pi-ups-hat-guide/

Warning: do not look at the code on that webpage, it is very bad for your eyes :-P

Comment: Conceptually similar to Scott’s answer to [Pre-authorise sudo? (So it can be run later)](https://superuser.com/a/640529/354511).

Answer (score 0):

In some cases (like some small embedded Linuxes, for example from standard yocto images) there is a group in `/etc/group` called `shutdown` which owns the executable for reboot. So in that case you just have to add this user to that group.