# Shutdown and reboot privileges

Tags: centos

While I tried 'reboot' through normal user (non-root), it went through. I tried 'shutdown' through same user, it also went through after scheduling the shutdown.

But when i tried sudo shutdown through same user, it didnt work.

error:

```
[rj@localhost ~]$ sudo shutdown
[sudo] password for rj: 
rj is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

Questions - How come a normal user do reboot or shutdown? Is it not a security concern ?

Question - if 'shutdown' is working, than why not 'sudo shutdown' ?

Request to pls explain.

Comment: The version of CentOS might be important here, but on a CentOS7 machine, ```which shutdown``` reveals that it's a symlink to /bin/systemctl.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect "sudo anything" would fail. The error message says there is no entry in the sudoers file authorizing rj to use sudo.

That is, the command did not fail because sudo doesn't like shutdown. What it doesn't like is folks who aren't defined as sudo users trying to use sudo.

As to whether or not it is good for unprivileged users to be able to execute shutdown, I yield to better informed opinion.

Answer (score 0):

As Robert netzlof said, ***shutdown*** did not fail, ***sudo*** failed.

It is a really bad idea to allow normal users to access the *shutdown* command; only root normally has access to that command, as it should be. That being said, it is possible to allow normal users to perform the *shutdown* command by creating a *shutdown* group and adding users to that group.

You can run the `groups` command to see who is in the current "shutdown" group (whatever it may be called).

Please see [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252708)